# PineScript: How to get only last day's OHLC instead of series of previous day OHLC?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get only last day's OHLC data on TradingView Pine Editor. If I use `security()` it gives the series of previous day data.

No matter, which timeframe the current chart is, I want the previous day's OHLC.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
previousDayO = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```